# Why is this proof that all four-fermion interactions are trivial incorrect?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, spinors, grassmann-numbers

Schwartz's quantum field theory text has an interesting question I haven't figured out:

> Consider a spinor interaction of the form $\overline{\psi}\psi\overline{\psi}\psi$. In the path integral formulation, spinors are Grassmann numbers, so this interaction would be represented as some product of Grassmann numbers $\theta_1 \theta_2 \theta_1 \theta_2$. However, since Grassmann numbers anticommute, this quantity is zero; thus the interaction does nothing at all. Is this argument correct?

The conclusion sounds wild -- do these interactions really automatically vanish? What's going on?

Comment: Stumbling on this again years later, what's going on is really simple: if the interaction is too big, you can't get all the fermions in the same place to do it because of the exclusion principle. For a four-point Dirac fermion interaction you need at least two Dirac fermions at the same place to do anything with it (i.e. $2 \to 2$ scattering), which is possible since, e.g. one can be spin up and one can be spin down. Even an eight-point Dirac fermion interaction is possible (spin up, spin down, and the antiparticle equivalents, i.e. the four spinor components). More than that is impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument is false in four dimensional space.  The error is the assumption that you get one Grassman number per spinor.  In fact, you get one Grassman number per spinor component!  In 4d, spinors have multiple components.  (Both Weyl spinors have 2 components, and Dirac spinors have 4.)

In 1d space, this is a correct argument.  In 2d, it is correct for Weyl spinors, but false for Dirac spinors.

Answer (score 7):

The reason your logic fails is because $\psi$ is not simply a Grassmann variable; it is a four-component vector of complex Grassmann numbers (in four dimensions):
\begin{equation}
\psi=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\theta_1 \\
\theta_2 \\
\theta_3 \\
\theta_4 \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
With this knowledge, try computing $\bar{\psi}\psi\bar{\psi}\psi$ and show that it
does not generically vanish. Bonus: what about $(\bar{\psi}\psi)^5$?

Comment: perfect, thanks! I'm still confused on one point. Before, I thought that spinors were elements of a 4-dimensional Grassmann algebra, with one dimension for each spinor component. Your answer says there's a separate Grasssmann number for each spinor component and implies that we're still in a 4-dimensional Grassmann algebra since $(\overline{\psi}\psi)^5$ vanishes.

Comment: if the Grassmann basis vectors don't correspond to spinor components, then why are there 4 of them?

Comment: @KevinZhou Why do you say that the Grassmann basis does not correspond to spinor components? Recall the canonical anticommutation relations for fermions. For classical fields (the path integral integrates over classical field configurations) all anticommutators vanish. So, in 4 spatial dimensions a Dirac spinor has 4 anticommuting spinor components, hence a 4-dimensional complex Grassmann algebra.